Potential on concentric shells not making sense?
Suppose you have 2 concentric spherical shells, radius $A$ (inner) and $B$ (outer). Now suppose the inner shell has $+Q$ charge and the outer one has $-Q$ charge. Through integration, we get that the potential difference between them is
$$V = - \int_b^a \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{l} = - \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_b^a \frac{1}{r^2} \mathrm{d}r = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \left(\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b}\right).$$
But this is not making sense for me because if we put a positive value (positive charge) in q, then the change in potential would be positive, which is odd, since it is obvious that the positive charge would go to a place of less potential, therefore losing potential.
Am I misunderstanding something?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks

What do you mean by putting a positive q in this?

Welcome to Physics! Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use MathJax instead.

A positive charge will move opposite the potential gradient if acted on by the electric field alone. So everything is fine. $V>0$ here means that the potential at $a$ is higher than the potential at $b$, so the positive charge placed between the shells will move radially outward, which is consistent with what we would expect for the positive charge to move away from the positively charged shell and towards the negatively charged shell.
To put it another way, force points opposite the potential energy gradient; think of a ball falling near Earth's surface. As the ball falls it loses potential energy. Same thing here, except when working with fields and potentials we are just talking about it all on a "per charge" basis.

What is making me confused is that, as you said, a positive charge would move radially outward, towards the shell of less potential, but if we try and calculate the change in potential of a positive charge by going from shell A to shell B (just by replacing Q in the equation by a positive value of charge), it would appear to be positive, wich makes no sense.

@AankNum I'm not following... Replacing $Q$ with $q$ isn't how you calculate the change in potential. Your integral is the change in potential for any charge. That's the purpose of potential; it's change in energy per unit charge. The $Q$ in your integral in the charge on the sphere, you aren't going to be replacing that.

Then it is a misunderstanding of mine, but I think I got it now. Thank you very much

Start with both concentric spheres uncharged and isolated so the potential difference between them is zero.
Move positive charge $q>0$ from the outer sphere radius $b$ to the inner sphere radius $a$, ie $b>a$.
The potential of inner sphere is greater than the potential of the outer sphere, ie external work will need to be done to move more positive charge from the outer sphere to the inner sphere.
$V_\text{inner sphere relative to outer sphere} =  \dfrac{\overbrace{q}^\text{positive}}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \overbrace{\left(\dfrac{1}{a} - \dfrac{1}{b}\right)}^{\text{positive}}$.

What if we want to know the change in potential of a negative charge when it goes from the outer sheel to the inner one? Or the opposite, a positive charge from the inner shell to the outer one? How would we calculate it?
